# Does the insert query need three quotation marks?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector

I frequently see (in this forum and elsewhere) SQL insert queries wrapped in three consecutive quotation marks, example:

```
query = """INSERT INTO test (value0, value1) VALUES (%s, %s)"""
mycursor.execute(query, ("foo","bar"))
```

I want to be able to iterate over table names. So when I use one quotation mark only, the query works just as well.

```
table1 = "test1" 
query = "".join(("INSERT INTO ", table1," (value0, value1) VALUES (%s, %s)"))
mycursor.execute(query, ("foo","bar"))
```

Which syntax is correct now?

Comment: The three quotation string syntax is only needed for multiline strings.  That being said, it _works_ for your first version, but just isn't necessary.  It isn't necessary in the second version either.

Answer (score 2):

[Triple quotes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#text-sequence-type-str) are used for strings that span multiple lines. They're a convenient shorthand to write readable indented code in strings. If your string is just one line you don't need them and `'abc' == '''abc'''` (same with double quotes).

See the following example of a longer query string:

```
"select column1, column2, column3 "\
"from table1 t1"\
"  join table2 t2 on t1.some_id_field = t2.another_id_field "\
"where column4 = 1"\
"   and column5 is not null"\
"   -- and so on"
```

This is a lot of typing and error prone if you forget the trailing `' '` (so that you get `... column3from ...`). The same with triple quotes is much easier to read and write:

```
"""select column1, column2, column3
   from table1 t1
      join table2 t2 on t1.some_id_field = t2.another_id_field
   where column4 = 1
      and column5 is not null
      -- and so on
"""
```

---

P.S.: Instead of

```
table1 = "test1" 
query = "".join(("INSERT INTO ", table1," (value0, anycode) VALUES (%s, %s)"))
```

I'd always use

```
query = f"INSERT INTO {table1} (value0, anycode) VALUES (%s, %s)"
```

because it's not only easier to read but it makes it far less probable to forget the spaces around the table name.

Comment: thx a lot for the explanations, I appreciate. As to the f-strings: I can't use them since still on 3.5, but  that would indeed be a better choice.

Comment: you still could use `"INSERT INTO {} (value0, anycode) VALUES (%s, %s)".format(table1)` on 3.5